# Access from gcloud ml-engine jobs to Big Query

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-ml

I have a python ML process which connects to `BigQuery` using a local `json` file which the env variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is pointing to (The file contains my keys supplied by google, see [authentication getting-started](http://https:/https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) )

When Running it locally its works great.

Im now looking to deploy my model through [Google's Ml engine](http://https:/cloud.google.com/ml-engine/), specifically using the shell command  `gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training`.

However, after i ran my process and looked at the logs in `console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer` i saw that gcloud cant access `Bigquery` and i'm getting the following error:

```
 google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File:
 /Users/yehoshaphatschellekens/Desktop/google_cloud_xgboost/....-.....json was not found.
```

Currently i don't think that the `gcloud  ml-engine jobs submit training` takes the Json file with it (I thought that gcloud has access automatically to BigQuery, i guess not)

One optional workaround to this is to save my personal  .json into my python dependancies in the other sub-package folder (see [packaging-trainer](http://https:/cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/packaging-trainer)) and import it.

Is this solution feasible / safe ?

Is there any other workaround to this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i did eventually is to upload the json to a `gcloud` storage bucket and then uploading it into my project each time i launch the ML-engine train process:

```
os.system('gsutil cp gs://secured_bucket.json .')
os.environ[ "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "......json"
```

Answer (score 2):

the path should be absolute and with backslashes in Windows:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\username\Downloads\[FILE_NAME].json"
```

set it this way in your Python code:

```
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "C:\PATH.JSON"
```

Example with the Google Translate API [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication).

Comment: thanks for the help, but i dont think it helps, i need to provide the ML engine access to BigQuery, and passing my own Json to it may be problematic / Not best practive

Comment: this a legit way to authenticate a user/service against any web API. You can use the API service account and add the role/permission that grant the access to BigQuery. Alternatively you can pass an API Key for each single request. Check here for more info: https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/common/auth